# Looking for Interactive Charting Software

Tags: charts, spreadsheet

Looking for charting/visualization software that will provide an interactive line chart.  It will need to render tabular data graphically (line or scatter chart).  My additional requirement is that the data should be adjustable directly from the chart by dragging the data points as needed and updating the respective table.

I've tried Excel and Google Sheets and they do not offer this feature to my knowledge.

Comment: Welcome aboard. Do you want this to be stand-alone, or maybe some JS that you can integrate into a web site? Good question, btw :-)

Comment: Hoping to find something open source.  And because it will be sourcing from a flat table it would be easy enough to copy the data in and out.  With that, can be standalone. I am only using it as a tool and it would not be published but the ability to export the graph would be nice.

Comment: Open source, of no money (gratis)? You might want to add a tag for one of those. If you don't intend to hack the code, you will probably get more answers with [tag:gratis], which includes [tag:open-source]

Comment: This is not a job listing or work request.  Hoping that a solution or software exists.  If no one has a solution or suggestion, I may need to consider customization or other paid solution.

Comment: When I Gogole for `Interactive Charting Software`, the first hit says `Datawrapper is an online tool for making interactive charts`. Doesn't Google help you any?

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear. Do you need this software to run on web, or desktop, mobile? How do you input the data? We are a charting software manufacturer, so maybe you would like to have this kind of software custom-made for you?